# Limiting http interceptor to specific domain

Tags: angularjs

I'm busy in building a little backoffice Web client in Angular.JS which directly talks to my API. For authentication I use OAUTH2 where I use an http interceptor to include the access token to a request. But, the interceptor is global, so not only my requests/responses to the API are checked, but also any other http call, like static html and templates.

I would like to bind the interceptor to my API calls only.

Would this be possible without a nasty domain-string-comparing-if-statement in the interceptor?

Comment: Yes, you don't have to use _"nasty domain-string-comparing-if-statement"_. Just us a normal domain-string-comparing-if-statement.

Comment: So that means that every request where I know from it has to go to the API domain I have to solve it by checking the string in the URL it is send to? That sounds not very efficient (strcmp on _every_ http call)

Comment: How do you imagine it could be otherwise achieved ? Even if there was a method to set specific interceptor for a domain, how do you expect Angular could achieve it internally if not by comparing a string ? How else could it know if the URL is destined to a specific domain or not ? You could also set the headers per request (if e.g. you make all the domain-specific requests from one place (e.g. a service)).

Comment: Indeed, that is what I say... I know I'm doing an API request (from multiple services off course) so I can solve it overthere but that is a lot of code duplication. My question is whether that can be solved by a "scoped" interceptor, specifically for those requests. A helper which decorates the http requests could also be the answer... I'm just looking for the most elegant solution as I'm quite new to Angular.JS ;)

Comment: I would probably use one of two: 1.) Either a "global" interceptor that checks for the domain and sets the header if necessary (yeah, nasty, string-matching thingy) 2.) Or a service that handles those types of requests and sets the header for each request made using the service's methods.

Comment: Thanks, please put your comment as an answer. So my API-model-services will depend on a generic APIHttpService which is basically a $http wrapper, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a service-wrapper around `$http` that takes care of OAuth specific stuff (e.g. adding a header etc) and use that service (instead of `$http`) for OAuth related requests.

---

Sample implementation:

```
app.factory('HttpOAuth', function ($http) {
    // Augments the request configuration object 
    // with OAuth specific stuff (e.g. some header)
    function getAugmentedConfig(cfg) {
        var config  = cfg || {};
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        config.headers.someHeaderName = 'some-header-value';
        return config;
    }

    // The service object to be returned (`$http` wrapper)
    var serviceObj = {};

    // Create wrappers for methods WITHOUT data
    ['delete', 'get', 'head', 'jsonp'].forEach(function (method) {
        serviceObj[method] = function (url, config) {
            var config = getAugmentedConfig(config);
            return $http[method](url, config);
        };
    });

    // Create wrappers for methods WITH data
    ['post', 'put'].forEach(function (method) {
        serviceObj[method] = function (url, data, config) {
            var config = getAugmentedConfig(config);
            return $http[method](url, data, config);
        };
    });

    // Return the service object
    return serviceObj;
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/QkAc8/)**.